# Representation of spin in the Fock space

Tags: quantum-spin, representation-theory

I understand that states of single 1/2-spin particle is just the unique (up to an isomorphism) irreducible representation of $\text{su}(2)_\mathbb{C} = \text{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ with dimension 2, but what about its Fock space?

So let me elaborate. Let $\Lambda$ be the 4-dim Fock space of  1/2-spin so that it is spanned by the orthonormal basis $\left|\text{vac} \right\rangle ,\left|\uparrow \right\rangle, \left|\downarrow \right\rangle, \left| \uparrow \downarrow \right\rangle$. Let $c_\sigma, c_\sigma^*$ be the corresponding annihilation and creation operators. Then I have seen textbooks define spin operators by $S^a = c_\sigma^* \tau^a_{\sigma,\bar{\sigma}} c_\bar{\sigma}/2$ where $\tau^a,a=1,2,3$ are the Pauli matrices. It's clear that the spin operators $S^a$ satisfy the same commutation relations as $\tau^a/2$. Then I would like to think that $S^a$ form the basis of the Lie algebra representation of $\text{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ on the Fock space $\Lambda$, from which we could decompose the Fock space into the direct sum of irreducible representations, namely spin $1/2$, spin $0$, and spin $0$. Is this the right understanding?

Comment: One of the $c$ in $S^a$ should have a barred $\sigma$ I guess...

Comment: Review your [Jordan map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_map), the basis of the Fock space *realization* you are outlining. You then see that You are describing *all* representations of su(2), not just the doublet. What does your text say?

Comment: @CosmasZachos I was reading Eduardo's book on condensed matter and just saw the definition of $S^a$ without much clarification. I never knew it was called the Jordan map.

Comment: @CosmasZachos And just for clarification purpose, when you mean describe all representations of $\text{su}(2)$, you are implying that $c_\sigma$ are bosonic, i.e., satisfy the CCR? Because if they were fermionic, I can't see how they would realize spin 1 and higher

Comment: Yes, boson, of course.